# R - Conditionally select within duplicate IDs and index

Tags: r

I have a data frame with duplicated IDs and different variables, like so:

```
x <- 1:10
ID <- c(20,20,55,55,45,45,45,45,45,45)
fruit <- c("Orange", "Apple", "Pear", "Apple", "Blueberries", "Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Strawberry", "Pear")
df <- cbind(x, ID, fruit)

> df
X   ID   fruit
1   20   Orange
2   20   Apple
3   20   Pear
4   55   Apple
5   55   Blueberries
6   45   Apple
7   45   Banana
8   45   Banana
9   45   Strawberry
10  45   Pear
```

I need to conditionally index certain attributes according to a hierarchy (e.g. Orange > Blueberries > Pear > Banana > Apple > Strawberry) *within* the duplicated IDs to acquire:

```
X   ID   fruit
1   20   Orange
5   55   Blueberries
10  45   Pear
```

Truly, I have no good/uncomplicated ideas on how to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: I gather you don't want to use `df <- cbind(...)` as that makes a matrix. Did you mean `df <- data.frame(...)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We `arrange` the 'ID', 'fruit' based on the `levels` specified in the 'OP's post, and 'X' in 'descending' order, then grouped by 'ID', `slice` the first row

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(ID, factor(fruit, levels = c('Orange', 'Blueberries', 'Pear', 
             'Banana','Apple', 'Strawberry')), desc(X)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  slice(1)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#      X    ID fruit      
#  <int> <int> <chr>      
#1     1    20 Orange     
#2    10    45 Pear       
#3     5    55 Blueberries
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X = 1:10, ID = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 55L, 55L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L), fruit = c("Orange", "Apple", "Pear", "Apple", 
"Blueberries", "Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Strawberry", "Pear"
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want one row in each group and every group would have the required `fruit` we can create a separate vector to store the hierarchy and subset it based on groups using `mapply`.

```
hierarc_vec <- c("Orange","Blueberries", "Pear", "Banana","Apple","Strawberry")
ids <- unique(df$ID)

df[mapply(function(x, y) which.max(df$ID == x & df$fruit == y), 
                     ids, hierarc_vec[1:length(ids)]), ]


#    x ID       fruit
#1   1 20      Orange
#5   5 55 Blueberries
#10 10 45        Pear
```

**data**

```
x <- 1:10
ID <- c(20,20,55,55,55,45,45,45,45,45)
fruit <- c("Orange", "Apple", "Pear", "Apple", "Blueberries", 
           "Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Strawberry", "Pear")
df <- data.frame(x, ID, fruit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Love them or hate them, this is what factors were designed to do.

```
library('dplyr')

x <- 1:10
ID <- c(20,20,55,55,45,45,45,45,45,45)
fruit <- c("Orange", "Apple", "Pear", "Apple", "Blueberries", "Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Strawberry", "Pear")
df <- cbind(x, ID, fruit)

df %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    mutate(fruit = factor(
        fruit,
        levels = c('Orange','Blueberries','Pear','Banana','Apple','Strawberry'),
        ordered = T
    )) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    arrange(fruit, ID) %>%
    slice(1)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
  x     ID    fruit      
  <fct> <fct> <ord>      
1 1     20    Orange     
2 5     45    Blueberries
3 3     55    Pear
```